# How do I pass an objects attribute as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example say I have this function using the nodes classification :

```
function example(){

var exampleVar = nodes.classfication;

//below i use exampleVar to do calculations
.
.
.
.
}
```

but say sometimes i want to get the nodes status so I do this :

```
function example(){

    var exampleVar = nodes.status;

    //below i use exampleVar to do calculations
    .
    .
    .
    .
    }
```

I dont want repeating code as (in my code) there is quite a lot of code in the function i want to reuse. So depending what I want to get out of this function ill pass it to the function like so :

```
function example(thisAttribute){

    var exampleVar = nodes.thisAttribute; //using the variable passed to the function

    //below i use exampleVar to do calculations
    .
    .
    .
    .
    }
```

This doesn't work, how do I go about passing an object attribute as a parameter to a function ? I've tried looking online but I dont think Im searching for the correct things as I can't find anything to help. Thanks in advance anyway :)

Comment: Related, potential duplicate: [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [**object bracket notation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation):

```
function example(thisAttribute){
  var exampleVar = nodes[thisAttribute];
}
```

Comment: ahh very nice, I didn't know that. Thanks alot :D